# Data type to store non-numeric registration number in a table

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, sqldatatypes

I'm very new to databases and creating a table to store details of some students.

Their student registration numbers are like this : 12/AS/CI/99

So, what's the best data type to store this value in the table ?

Comment: Is the length fixed?

Comment: I'm sorry, "fixed" means ? All the numbers will be in this format eg: 9/MS/TM/55

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that `12/AS/CI/99` is not a datum (even though the user perceives it as one RegistrationNo), therefore it should not be placed in a single column.

First Normal Form requires data to be Atomic.

Determine what each of those four items are, and implement four columns.  Probably RegistrationYear, HomeState, Fish, BirthYear.

That will allow full capability (look-ups, searches, aggregation, etc) on each of the component columns.

Yes, that means the Key will be four columns.  Compound Keys are normal in relational databases.

Yes, that means you will have to concatenate the four columns with "/" in-between, wherever you display it to the user, as a single field (note the distinction between *column* and *field*) labelled `RegistrationNo`.  That too, is normal.

If you do not do that, if you store it as a alpha-numeric column, you won't have a database, or any of the facilities people expect from databases.  Eg. if you search for students who have `AS` in their RegistrationNo, the query will tablescan (Peanut's advice is incorrect), whereas if the components were separated columns, it will be blindingly fast, because the Key (in any number of component columns) is indexed. The student Key should be indexed in whatever table it occurs in.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CHAR(length)` if the length of your ID is known (and fix).

Comment: Thanks.. so, by using char can I search them ?

Comment: What kind of search do you want?  Search only for equality (`WHERE regno = '11/AA/VV/88'`)?  Or do you need to search on the pieces.  So far, `VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET ascii` seems reasonable.